# How to only auto resize certain NSTableColumn?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, interface-builder

I have a table with 3 columns (NSTableColumn) build with XCode IB.

The last column is "Amount" and the column before it is "Description. When I resize the window, the table will be resize as well but the "Amount" is the column that gets span wider.

How do I fixed the "Amount" column width and instead auto resize the "Description" column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the inspector for each of the table columns in Interface Builder.

For the ones that you want to maintain their width uncheck the 'Resizes with table' option.

For the columns that you want to have change their width, make sure it is checked.